# Scala - shell commands with pipe

Tags: scala

I'm a Scala beginner and I'm writing a wrapper for invoking shell commands. Currently I'm trying to invoke shell commands with pipes from a specified directory.

To achieve this I wrote simple utility:

```
def runCommand(command: String, directory: File): (Int, String, String) = {

  val errbuffer = new StringBuffer();
  val outbuffer = new StringBuffer();

  //run the command
  val ret = sys.process.Process(command, directory) !
  //log output and err
  ProcessLogger(outbuffer append _ + "\n", outbuffer append _ + "\n");

  return (ret, outbuffer.toString(), errbuffer.toString());
}
```

However with this utility I can't use pipes, for example:

```
runCommand("ps -eF | grep -i foo", new File("."));
```

First I thought, that pipes are shell's functionality, so I tried "/bin/sh -c ps -eF | grep -i foo", but it seems that expression from the right of the pipe was ignored.

I also tried running commands with ! syntax (sys.process._ package), but I couldn't figure out, how to call command from specified directory (without using "cd").

Could you please advice me, how to do this correctly?

Comment: @xhochy OK. I removed the comment so that nobody can accidentaly use it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
val ret = sys.process.Process(command, directory) !
```

to

```
val ret = sys.process.stringSeqToProcess(Seq("/bin/bash", "-c", "cd " + directory.getAbsolutePath + ";" + command))
```

Or you could directly use the magic provided by Scala:

```
import.scala.sys.process._
val ret = "ps -ef" #| "grep -i foo" !
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I get this error: -eF: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-eF: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @altanis Oh, Scala seems to remove the ' ticks sometimes. I updated my answer with a solution that should work (I think the best would be to use the Scala magic where you enter the pipe as a function (the last example).

Comment: @altanis - Seems you have a redundant quote in your command. Try printing the `directory.getAbsolutePath + ";" + command` to output, maybe that would solve it.

Comment: @Rogach The first comment of altanis refers to an older answer of mine. In the updated version this problem should be gone.

Comment: @xhochy Thanks, now it works correctly. The only thing that I changed is: /bin/bash -> /bin/sh.

Comment: In the first case (the one without the magic) won't it break if the directory path has spaces? Do you know if there is a way around that?